# Possible to destroy record and return remaining records?

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm making a request to DELETE a record, but then want to immediately query remaining records. How can I query remaining records after the DELETE is successful.

So far I have this where I make the DELETE request and then query based on the status code (1 is a success, 0 is failure), but wondering if there is a better way to handle this:

```
app.delete('/projects', (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.query;
  Item
    .destroy({ where: { id: id } })
    .then(status => {
      if (status === 1) {
        // make query here, something like:
        // Item.findAll().then(...)
      }
    })
    .catch(err => err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your only option of doing it in a single call to the database would be to wrap it in a stored procedure. In this case I don't see any real advantages to doing it that way and would recommend using two calls as you have in your example.